# How to perform spark application logging

Tags: logging, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I use logging within a spark application?

The problem is that sparks code will not be executed as written, but async and optimized e.g. possibly in different order.

As it was pointed out to me here [stylish spark dataset transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585845/stylish-spark-dataset-transformation) 
the following should not work / not necessarily work as expected in the optimized query plan of spark:

```
logger.info("first")
val first = df.someTransformation
logger.info("second")
val second = df.otherTransformation
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to log? Can you give a real-world example of the content you want to log?

Comment: I want to perform several data cleaning steps and would like to monitor the progress. For each step I want to output a logging message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log-statements in you example aren't very meaningful.

I see 3 ways of logging:

a) If you just want to log the "progress" of your transformation as you show in your example, you have to apply an action (e.g. call `count()`) after your transformation, but this causes unnecessary computations

b) montior spark using spark UI, and look into settings like `spark.eventLog.enabled` to persists the output

c) inside UDFs/UDAFs, you could use accumulators to collect the logs of the executors and make them accessible for the driver.

Comment: so you would suggest to write a logging UDF?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler No. But if you work with UDFs to make complex transformations, you could add logging to this code